# Removed npmlog folder and now I can't use npm

Tags: node.js, npm, linux-mint

I'm a beginner in linux and npm in general, at first I screwed my npm installation by doing this :

```
npm conig set prefix usr/bin/env
```

I really don't know what I was really doing here, but then I got an EExist error whenever I run npm .

I decided to remove npm and node via :

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove node
```

And the reinstalled them normally via the apt-get command . I had the same error, so I did a very immature thing and I deleted all folder containing the word npm, and more importantly npmlog, uninstlled and reinstalled node and npm via apt .

Now I'm having this error that I couldn't fix whenevr I use the npm command .

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:86:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I tried reinstalling, removing other npm folders in node_modules, but none of those techniques worked for me, please how can I fix this ?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing you should be doing if you want to learn.  Kudos !

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just a bit frustrated, learning is making mistakes :) .